# How do I list all the projects in the current solution using EnvDTE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte

I've been following [MSDN's Hello World guide to developing Visual Studio extensions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/ide/extensions/hello_world) (this article specifically deals with creating one as a Visual Studio toolbar command).

I am trying to list all projects contained in the current/active solution.

In the auto generated code for the Command template.

I have tried `EnvDTE`'s `Solution`'s `Projects` property, but it shows zero projects.

There is a `ActiveSolutionProjects` property as well, but it also shows an empty array.

How is this achieved ?

**P.S.: I tried both DTE and DTE2 interfaces since it is confusing understanding which version to use, from the docs. I get a null service for DTE2, so I am going with DTE.**

[image]

My Solution Explorer looks like:

[image]

---

**Update**: Bert Huijben, from [gitter/extendvs](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/extendvs), suggested the following, found at the [VSSDK Extensibility Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/851c912e2f5b20d3c8b2f47f8470df326431d071/Source_Control_Provider_Status_Bar_Integration/C%23/SccProvider.cs#L746) - but this too does not work (returns 0 elements, both within the constructor and within the callback function):

```
private Hashtable GetLoadedControllableProjectsEnum()
{
    Hashtable mapHierarchies = new Hashtable();

    IVsSolution sol = (IVsSolution)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));
    Guid rguidEnumOnlyThisType = new Guid();
    IEnumHierarchies ppenum = null;
    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(sol.GetProjectEnum((uint)__VSENUMPROJFLAGS.EPF_LOADEDINSOLUTION, ref rguidEnumOnlyThisType, out ppenum));

    IVsHierarchy[] rgelt = new IVsHierarchy[1];
    uint pceltFetched = 0;
    while (ppenum.Next(1, rgelt, out pceltFetched) == VSConstants.S_OK &&
           pceltFetched == 1)
    {
        IVsSccProject2 sccProject2 = rgelt[0] as IVsSccProject2;
        if (sccProject2 != null)
        {
            mapHierarchies[rgelt[0]] = true;
        }
    }

    return mapHierarchies;
}
```

Comment: From a quick skim of the code, that _should_ work. What is this.ServiceProvider getting? Does anything change if you instead do GetService(typeof(SDTE)), but leave the casts as are?

Comment: In the Command1 constructor a solution is probably not yet loaded. Try to move your code to MenuItemCallback.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: it gets a `System.__ComObject`, which contains a `Solution` property, which in turn contains a `Projects` property. I tried SDTE as you suggested, but SDTE is an empty interface, so it does not help much.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov: Tried moving the code there as well, same thing.

Comment: @Veverke: I meant you use SDTE in the GetService argument, but you still cast it to the regular interface. There's no rule those both have to be the same.

Comment: BY saying "My Solution Explorer" you mean the one in the experimental instance correct? As in you launch as debug and then open a solution in the experimental instance that launches?

Answer (score 7):

To get the EnvDTE.Project objects:

```
    static private void FindProjectsIn(EnvDTE.ProjectItem item, List<EnvDTE.Project> results)
    {
        if (item.Object is EnvDTE.Project)
        {
            var proj = (EnvDTE.Project)item.Object;
            if (new Guid(proj.Kind) != Utilities.ProjectTypeGuids.Folder)
            {
                results.Add((EnvDTE.Project)item.Object);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (EnvDTE.ProjectItem innerItem in proj.ProjectItems)
                {
                    FindProjectsIn(innerItem, results);
                }
            }
        }
        if (item.ProjectItems != null)
        {
            foreach (EnvDTE.ProjectItem innerItem in item.ProjectItems)
            {
                FindProjectsIn(innerItem, results);
            }
        }
    }

    static private void FindProjectsIn(EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem item, List<EnvDTE.Project> results)
    {
        if (item.Object is EnvDTE.Project)
        {
            var proj = (EnvDTE.Project)item.Object;
            if (new Guid(proj.Kind) != Utilities.ProjectTypeGuids.Folder)
            {
                results.Add((EnvDTE.Project)item.Object);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (EnvDTE.ProjectItem innerItem in proj.ProjectItems)
                {
                    FindProjectsIn(innerItem, results);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem innerItem in item.UIHierarchyItems)
        {
            FindProjectsIn(innerItem, results);
        }
    }

    static internal IEnumerable<EnvDTE.Project> GetEnvDTEProjectsInSolution()
    {
        List<EnvDTE.Project> ret = new List<EnvDTE.Project>();
        EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
        EnvDTE.UIHierarchy hierarchy = dte.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;
        foreach (EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem innerItem in hierarchy.UIHierarchyItems)
        {
            FindProjectsIn(innerItem, ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Notably recursion is necessary to dig into solution folders.

If you just want the file paths you can do this w/o using DTE:

```
    static internal string[] GetProjectFilesInSolution()
    {
        IVsSolution sol = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
        uint numProjects;
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(sol.GetProjectFilesInSolution((uint)__VSGETPROJFILESFLAGS.GPFF_SKIPUNLOADEDPROJECTS, 0, null, out numProjects));
        string[] projects = new string[numProjects];
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(sol.GetProjectFilesInSolution((uint)__VSGETPROJFILESFLAGS.GPFF_SKIPUNLOADEDPROJECTS, numProjects, projects, out numProjects));
        //GetProjectFilesInSolution also returns solution folders, so we want to do some filtering
        //things that don't exist on disk certainly can't be project files
        return projects.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) && System.IO.File.Exists(p)).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: This recursive solution is very good, with two problems: 1. It will crash on unloaded folders (need to check for `null` after each `var proj = (EnvDTE.Project)item.Object;`) and 2. It goes recursive twice for solution folders, winding up with duplicate projects in list, so you need an `else` before the  `foreach (EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem innerItem in item.UIHierarchyItems)` and the `if (item.ProjectItems != null)`

Comment: 'sol' always returns null.

Comment: Does not work for complex solution hierarchies. I will post my own solution.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately could not find any working solution here, decided to post my own solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Queries for all projects in solution, recursively (without recursion)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sln">Solution</param>
/// <returns>List of projects</returns>
static List<Project> GetProjects(Solution sln)
{
    List<Project> list = new List<Project>();
    list.AddRange(sln.Projects.Cast<Project>());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        // OfType will ignore null's.
        list.AddRange(list[i].ProjectItems.Cast<ProjectItem>().Select(x => x.SubProject).OfType<Project>());

    return list;
}
```

And if you don't know what references / namespaces to add, you can pick up project with source code from here:

https://github.com/tapika/cppscriptcore/blob/2a73f45474c8b2179774fd4715b8d8e80080f3ae/Tools/vsStart/Program.cs#L478

And check namespaces / references.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

Add a field in your package for dte.
Get the DTE service.
Reference the Solution.

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
```

In your constructor:

```
dte = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
```

In your command handler:

```
Integer count = ((EnvDTE.SolutionClass)dte.Solution).Projects.Count;
```

I get the correct count from this.

Screenshot (requested)

[image]

Code

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="Command1.cs" company="Company">
//     Copyright (c) Company.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

namespace SolExpExt
{
    internal sealed class Command1
    {
        public const int CommandId = 0x0100;
        public static readonly Guid CommandSet = new Guid("beff5a1a-dff5-4f6a-95c8-fd7ea7411a7b");
        private DTE2 dte;
        private readonly Package package;
        private IVsSolution sol;
        private Command1(Package package)
        {
            if (package == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("package");
            }

            this.package = package;

            OleMenuCommandService commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
            if (commandService != null)
            {
                var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
                var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);
                commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
            }

            dte = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
        }

        public static Command1 Instance
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        private IServiceProvider ServiceProvider
        {
            get
            {
                return this.package;
            }
        }

        public static void Initialize(Package package)
        {
            Instance = new Command1(package);
        }

        private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = $"There are {dte.Solution.Projects.Count} projects in this solution.";
            string title = "Command1";

            VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
                this.ServiceProvider,
                message,
                title,
                OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of the whole IDE window, showing the solution explorer along with the code ? What you suggests above still does not work for me. I still get 0 projects. So you are getting 1 ?

Comment: @Veverke did that help?

Comment: Hey thanks for the new feedback, I was on vacation, will check this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The following, shamelessly taken from [AutoFindReplace](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/AutoFindReplace/blob/master/AutoFindReplace/VSPackage.cs), works using VS2015 Community:

```
using EnvDTE;
.
.
protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();

    IServiceContainer serviceContainer = this as IServiceContainer;
    dte = serviceContainer.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
    var solutionEvents = dte.Events.SolutionEvents;
    solutionEvents.Opened += OnSolutionOpened;

    var i = dte.Solution.Projects.Count; // Happy days !
}
```

All the code lines above pre-exist in the [solution](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/AutoFindReplace/blob/master/AutoFindReplace.sln) within [VSPackage.cs](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/AutoFindReplace/blob/master/AutoFindReplace/VSPackage.cs) except for "var i = dte.Solution.Projects.Count;" which I added locally to [VSPackage.cs](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/AutoFindReplace/blob/master/AutoFindReplace/VSPackage.cs) just after line [44](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/AutoFindReplace/blob/master/AutoFindReplace/VSPackage.cs#L44). I then open the [solution](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/AutoFindReplace/blob/master/AutoFindReplace.sln), hit F5, and within the Experimental Instance I opened [JoePublic.Sln](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/AutoFindReplace/blob/master/JoePublic.zip) and hey presto the count was '2' correctly - Bingo ! Happy days !