# How can I Enumerate Projects/Files in a Visual Studio Solution Extension?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, vsix

I would like to obtain a collection of all `.cs` files in a solution for analysis from a Visual Studio Extension. There are a couple methods of doing this on SO, but these are outdated and clunky. Specifically, they utilize old COM compatibility libraries, and require casting and inspecting GUIDs stored as strings.

- [How do I list all the projects in the current solution using EnvDTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126032/how-do-i-list-all-the-projects-in-the-current-solution-using-envdte)
- [Enumerate all files in current visual studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374282/enumerate-all-files-in-current-visual-studio-project)
- [Visual Studio Extension get all classes and interfaces metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791188/visual-studio-extension-get-all-classes-and-interfaces-metadata)

Any method which also gives access to some parse tree would be especially useful (in my case).

Comment: "*There are a couple methods of doing this on SO, but these are outdated and clunky*" Do you have a specific problem with above solutions? Why do they not work for you? [Related meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318454/2441442)

Comment: They utilize old COM compatibility libraries, and require casting and inspecting GUIDs stored as strings. I'm hopeful that the visual studio team has something more modern that integrates well with C# and doesn't require verbose code to use.

Comment: Thank your for clarifying this. Please [edit] your question to reflect that comment, it might help you to get the answer you realy want @pensono